# What was that movie where people drilling in an asteroid awaken a monster?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched this movie on TV 10-15 years ago, and I remember the title as it was translated to my native language, when I translate it back to English, it was something like "The Rock" or "The stone" (meaning the asteroid I assume).

An asteroid is headed for earth, so a team is sent to destroy it. They find that the asteroid is rich in platinum. They drill to the core and find a (man-made, or alien-made) chamber with the remains of a creature. They return to their camp and they turn off the oxygen supply. Once there is no oxygen and only nitrogen atmosphere, the creature regenerates, because it was the oxygen that prevented it from doing so while the people were in the chamber. I remember how one of the men went back to the chamber later and when he didn't find the remains said "She [one of the scientists] didn't have enough with the pictures, she had to take the remains, too".

Then the creature starts killing people. Meanwhile they decode a message or inscription that they found on the wall before they broke into the chamber. It turns out it was a warning, saying that the creature had terrorized some planet until the people there managed to trap it in this platinum coffin, and that they ejected it into space. Later the coffin acrued rocks and thus became the asteroid.

That's as far as I remember the plot.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It was [Within The rock](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118183/).

> On a direct collision course with Earth, a large moon rapidly approaches from the outer regions of the solar system and Dr. Dana Shaw is sent along with a specialized mining crew to try to alter its course. Once upon the moon Shaw is faced not only with a brutal time schedule and a greedy, opportunistic crew captain, but with the release of a seemingly indestructible carnivorus alien, imprisoned within the moon eons ago by a race it had been slowly decimating.

This is what I googled: *alien in a platinum asteroid movie "The Rock"*

Comment: Good crikey, that looks [amazing](http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTcyMDE1NTg0Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzUxNjcxMQ@@._V1_SY317_CR11,0,214,317_.jpg).

Answer (score -3):

Was searching for it also and found "[Within the Rock](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118183/)" (1996).

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Stack Exchange. Quick note: this was already answered over two years ago. I suggest checking out the [Tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better idea of how to ask and answer questions. We're not a typical discussion forum. *Don't be discouraged, we were all new here at some point.*